# Why is my Dev C++ not accepting more than two libraries?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dev-c++

My application is only accepting these two libraries (#include<stdio.h> and #include<conio.h>). It does not accept any other library. It shows this error

[This is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ic9RA.png)

What should I do?

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/995714). `conio.h` and `graphics.h` aren't standard C++ headers

Comment: I would go further and ask why you're using dev-c++?

Comment: My computer teacher is teaching us coding on Dev C++

Comment: Yeah, but conio.h works, but the other libraries don't. that is my question why?